# Is it possible to check if pebble is connected to ANCS service from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

What I want to do is to notify user from background that something happened. On iOS device this is done using [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html). I also have an app on pebble watch to which I send a notification and user can interact with it.

**The issue** is that starting with iOS 8 pebble also shows **all** notifications from Notification Center, this way the notification gets duplicated.

To make things worse, pebble actually creates two different connections: (1)a simple Bluetooth link for normal communication and (2) a BluetoothLE for ANCS service: this means that the watch  can be "connected" but no connection for ANCS services is established.

Is there a way to determine this, so that I don't send the notification manually if pebble already receives it from ANCS services?

p.s. I do check if the device has BLE (using [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Central_Manager_Initialization_Options)), so this partially solves the issue - I send manually the notification for the devices that don't support BLE at all.